# How to report issue with Ubuntu 20 display selection after login?

Tags: 20.04

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu 20.
If the user/(technician) connects a different VGA display (what he happens to have in his truck) than what was installed with, it switches to a unconnected computer display and blanks the VGA display even though that is the display the user logged in on.  I believe this is a programming fault that could be corrected, but have no idea how to report this

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).   *You've implied twice you're using a snap only release (20) but tagged 20.04 - please clarify*

Comment: Sorry, 20.04 LTS is the operating system in question.

Comment: i'm still reading up on the how to report this, but this is going to be difficult for the following reasons: 1)All computers having this issue are off-line by LLNL security. 2)I'm uncertain what application performs the switch from the login to desktop display. Maybe someone could inform me what that application is.  3) I doubt this is related to a resolution problem, just that the operating system has recognized that there has been a VGA terminal change.